# How can I write an array to a specific excel sheet beginning at specific cell using Julia XLSX.jl?

Tags: julia, export-to-excel

Coming from MATLAB, the MATLAB way to write an array to a specific sheet and from a specific cell is straight forward:

```
xlswrite("filename",array,"sheetname2","cell")
```

I've tried reading the tutorials on how do do this using the Julia XLSX.jl package, but I just can't understand what's going on or how to do it. Is there a "straight forward" way to do this in Julia using XLSX.jl, or is there another package I could use that has easier syntax? At the beginning of my Julia script I have:

```
using DataFrames, XLSX
data = DataFrame(XLSX.readtable("filename","sheetname1")...)
```

which works just fine.

I must say, Julia is fast and free, but many Julia tutorials aren't written for the Julia newbie and leave alot of the syntax unexplained.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the other answer is not correct so here is mine.

Suppose you have the following Excel file with two sheets (BTW notice this very useful syntax for creating multi-sheet Excel files):

```
using XLSX, DataFrames
df = DataFrame(a=1:3, b=string.('a':'c'), d=0.1:0.1:0.3)
XLSX.writetable("file.xlsx", sheet1=(eachcol(df), names(df)),
                             sheet2=(eachcol(df), names(df)))
```

I understand the goal is to add some data to let's say `sheet1`. This can be accomplished by:

```
XLSX.openxlsx("file.xlsx", mode="rw") do xf
   XLSX.writetable!(xf["sheet1"], eachcol(df), names(df); anchor_cell=XLSX.CellRef("A6"))
end
```

Let us see the result:

[image]

If you rather want just to put a matrix use `setdata!`:

```
julia> mx = rand(3,2)
3×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.626637  0.245274
 0.560975  0.59444
 0.439289  0.0400645

julia> XLSX.openxlsx("file.xlsx", mode="rw") do xf
                XLSX.setdata!(xf["sheet1"], XLSX.CellRef("A6"), mx)
       end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Przemyslaw. But I just don't get this. I want to simply add and save generated data (array, NOT a table) into a specific sheet, beginning with a specific cell (anchor_cell). Where is the variable array name of the generated data in your second last line? Do I still need to name the column where the anchor_cell is? What is the difference between "eachcol(df)" and "names(df)"? What's xf? What's xf["sheet1"]? The tutorials are not clear at all.

Comment: I added writing a plain matrix at a specific anchor. `xf["sheet1"]` returns the Excel sheet named `sheet1`. Your other questions are not part of XLSX. `eachcol` and `names` are parts of `DataFrames` - try  typing `?eachcol` and `?names` to get the docs - the first returns a column iterator while the second returns column names. Check also `do` - block syntax to understand the code: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Do-Block-Syntax-for-Function-Arguments  and then you will understand how `xf` is obtained.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. XLSX.setdata! is what I was after. However I had to write the array one cell at a time in a loop. I think there was a type incompatibility between the XLSX.setdata! function and the array I wanted to write.

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally did it for me (A is the array name):

```
XLSX.openxlsx("filename", mode="rw") do xf
for i = 1:size(A,1)
XLSX.setdata!(xf["sheet"], XLSX.CellRef(1+i,4), A[i,1])
XLSX.setdata!(xf["sheet"], XLSX.CellRef(1+i,5), A[i,2])
end
end
```